# Database system for many read/writes per second

Tags: database, bigdata, nosql

I'm going to write my project in the client-server architecture. The main part of the system will be a database storage. There will be tens of thousands read/write requests per second. The raw structure of database will be very simple and can be even simplified to the key-value pairs. I'm going to use one of the NoSql database for this purpose. I need your architectural advice if it will be suitable for such case. Now I think about Apache Couch DB or Mongo DB. What is your experience in this area? Thank you for any knowledge sharing.

Comment: Not appropriate Question here. Perhaps the Software Recommendations Stack Exchange or the DBA Stack Exchange.

Comment: Software Recommendations Stack Exchange is rather for people who are looking for usable software and DBA Stack Exchange is about administrative questions. My opinion is about programming library recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

I could be hard to achieve required performance with Couch DB or Mongo DB. Better to simplify your model to key-value. After that you can use Cassandra. It's good for simple key/value structure and huge amount of write/read. You can take a look on Amazon Dynamo but price could be higher https://www.instaclustr.com/blog/2016/05/27/managed-cassandra-versus-dynamodb/ and noway for standalone deploy.